# ASP.NET and SqlDataAdapter with string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM [data_LookupValues] where Category = 'CanadaProvinces' ", con);
    myda.Fill(ds);
    ddlState.DataSource = ds;
    ddlState.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddlState.DataBind();
```

I am stuck as I need to put a string value of `CanadaProvinces` within the `SqlDataAdapter`.

Is there a easy way of doing this? I get an error when I do it the way I have it.

Comment: What's the error?  That code looks fine to me.

Comment: {"Incorrect syntax near '='."}

Comment: Does that query run normally in SQL Management studio (or some other query tool).

Comment: After your last edit, the query appears as correct. Do you still have the syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way would be to do a number of things:

1. wrap your disposable objects into `using` blocks
2. use a separate `SqlCommand` object and use a parametrized query (instead of concatenating together your SQL)
3. since you're only returning a single set of data - use a `DataTable` instead of the much "heavier" `DataSet`
4. separate the fetching of the data into its own method - and just call the from your web page - makes it universally useable, too! (will work for other things - not just `CanadaProvinces`)

So your code should be something like this:

```
private DataTable FetchData(string categoryValue)
{
   string query = "SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM [data_LookupValues] where Category = @Category";

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
   {
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = categoryValue;

       SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       DataTable result = new DataTable();

       myda.Fill(result);
       return result;
    }
}
```

and then in your ASPX web's code-behind, use something like this:

```
DataTable tblCanadaProvinces = FetchData('CanadaProvinces');  

ddlState.DataSource = tblCanadaProvinces;
ddlState.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlState.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlState.DataBind();
```

and be done with it. Now you can call your `FetchData` method to retrieve any possible category in your lookup table!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us the error, however, this is no valid sql:

```
SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM [data_LookupValues] = 'CanadaProvinces'
```

What do you want to query, is `data_LookupValues` a table in the database?

Perhaps this is what you actually want:

```
SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM [data_LookupValues] WHERE Provinces = 'CanadaProvinces'
```

Of course i've just assumed the correct column name.